# Mysql Service Won't Start

Tags: mysql, linux, centos

I have mysql running on linux environment under centos distributed and cPanel/WHM control panel

i track the mysql log and i got

```
130914  6:49:08 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130914  6:49:08 [ERROR] No paths allowed for shared library
130914  6:49:08 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named '68' with soname 'افص�حات افإضا�ٍة فكلتدٍات اف�ٍ بٍ'.
130914  6:49:08 [ERROR] Can't open shared library '/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/Cybernetec's Hacks Template Group' (errno: 0 cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
130914  6:49:08 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named '487' with soname 'Cybernetec's Hacks Template Group'.
130914  6:49:08 [ERROR] Can't open shared library '/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/Cyb - ChatBox - CT' (errno: 0 cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
130914  6:49:08 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named '488' with soname 'Cyb - ChatBox - CT'.
130914  6:49:08 [ERROR] Can't open shared library '/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/Cyb - ChatBox - IL' (errno: 0 cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
130914  6:49:08 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named '489' with soname 'Cyb - ChatBox - IL'.
130914  6:49:08 [ERROR] Can't open shared library '/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/[you]' (errno: 0 cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
130914  6:49:08 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named '93' with soname '[you]'.
130914  6:49:08 [ERROR] No paths allowed for shared library
130914  6:49:08 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named '117' with soname 'افإستبداف افآفٍ'.
```

i can start mysql with skip grant table option

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start --skip-grant-tables
```

Comment: what are those plugins? show more of your config.

Comment: please explain more about more of the config , you mean /etc/my.cnf config ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the mysql database was overwritten with other tables

i deleted the mysql folder in the path **/var/lib/mysql/**

i deleted the rpm mysql files by running commands

```
# rpm -qa | grep -i mysql  > /mysql.txt

# for i in `cat /mysql.txt`;do rpm -e $i;done
```

then i run

```
/scripts/upcp
```

to build mysql again

and i mysql is up and running again

Comment: Excellent answer, long term how do we solve? More RAM?

Answer (score 0):

Your Mysql configuration seems to be in bad shape.

1- Check if there are strange lines in your `my.cnf` configuration file starting with `'plugin-load'`. Such lines should look like: (should only contain references to .so files)

```
plugin-load=myplugin=somepluglib.so
```

2- Or maybe you have a corrupted `'mysql.plugin'` table (or maybe a filesystem corruption... hope you have backups...)

Comment: there is no plugin loaded in my.cnf

Comment: how to check if mysql.plugin table corrupted and how to fix it ?

Comment: run 'mysqldump mysql', and check the data. You may have a filesystem corruption, so I hope you have backups of your database...